# What is << Type? variableName >> syntax in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I found a syntax in a code Like this:

```
String? variableName;
```

I want to know what the use of the question mark here

Answer (score 0):

The question mark allows the variable to be null or makes the variable nullable.

[Dart Documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#nullable-variables)

Answer (score -1):

That syntax belongs to null-safety

[Null-Safety Guide](https://codewithandrea.com/videos/dart-null-safety-ultimate-guide-non-nullable-types/)

Answer (score -1):

It is the indicator that this variable might be `null`.

For more information, see [the Dart documentation on null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)